# Segmentation fault when cross compiling Windows compatible .exe from Linux development env

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, g++, mingw-w64

I use a Linux environment for code development and testing of a program and now I want to compile an Windows ".exe" file so that my program can run on Windows OS, after some internet research I tried to modified my makefile to use x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ instead of g++ as its compiler but now I get a segmentation fault at the end of the compilation and I am not sure how to debug this. My makefile is below:

```
PROGRAM=output.exe
COMPILER=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
# PROGRAM=output
# COMPILER=g++
#BIN_FOLDER=bin

DEPS += Defs.h Structs.h

CXXFLAGS+=`sdl2-config --cflags`
CXXFLAGS+=-DVERSION=$(VERSION) -DREVISION=$(REVISION) -DDATA_DIR=\"$(DATA_DIR)\"
CXXFLAGS+=-Wall -Wempty-body -Werror -Werror=maybe-uninitialized -Warray-bounds
CXXFLAGS+=-g -lefence -std=c++20 -fopenmp

LDFLAGS+=-L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -fopenmp src/ECS/*.cpp #-pg

FILENAME:=  $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard src/*.cpp))

$(PROGRAM):$(FILENAME)
    $(COMPILER) $(FILENAME) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm src/*.o
```

this compiles without a problem in g++ but when using the mingw32 compiler I get this error:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ src/ActionManager.o src/AStar.o ...[a bunch of .o files] -o output.exe 
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:26: output.exe] Error 1
```

I tried compiling a simple helloWorld.cpp program using x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ like this: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ 01_hello_world.c -o windowshello.exe` and that works fine.

I also tried deleting all my LDFLAGS just to see what would happen and I get the same result.

Could anyone point me into the right direction as to how I might debug this? Is this a particular part of my code that is causing this or am I going about this entirely wrong?

Comment: Well, `ld` shouldn't crash.  Are you sure you've got the latest mingw?

Comment: Are the libraries you are trying to link compiled for Windows?

Comment: Everything is compiled on Linux, the cpp files go to .o's according to $(PROGRAM):$(FILENAME). I am pretty sure I have the latest version of mingw as I just apt-get installed them prior to.